# PHP tag considered as a comment in Safari + Wamp

Tags: php, html, safari, mamp

I'm trying something in PHP HTML on MAMP. I insert PHP tags `<?php` and `?>` in my code. The problem: it is impossible to test my scipt as "something" is transforming my `<?php` and `?>` into `<!--?php` and `?-->` . Safari interprets it as comments. I also tried with Safari on a remote computer with Windows. No way to find the root of the problem.

[image: Printscreen]

Comment: Very odd indeed.  First question is: are you running this document through a web server and getting your output in the browser afterwards?  If so, next question: is your editor doing some "magic" to your document when you save it?  Open it in a text editor and see if the comments are being placed there.

Comment: I have found the solution... I used charset UTF-16. I changed it to charset UTF-8 and it works. Maybe somebody can explain this phenomenon. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

As I said in another comment, the problem comes from the charset. I selected UTF-16 instead of UTF-8. I don't really understand the subsequent problem but it is resolved.

Thank you.